# Storing big text data in database

Tags: node.js, text, text-files

I am trying to build a blogging site(sort of). **The users can write big blogs(or text) and also have facility for customisation like fonts, size, colour of text etc (*kind of like posts in stack overflow n little more*)**. I am looking to use mongo-db or couch-base for the database part. Now I am confused in few things

- **Where should I store the blogs or posts? In database or in text files?** If in database how will I store the fonts, size, colour(*user can have different fonts, sizes for different part of posts*)?? The posts can sometimes be very big, so is it advisable to store such large texts in database. I see the easier option to store them as files(text files) but I am worried about performance of the site as loading text files can be slow in websites. **Just for a knowledge sake, How does google store google docs files??**
- Should I use any other ***database which is more suited to handling the kind of things I mentioned***?
- Though ***Full search of texts*** in the post is not a feature I am looking into right now, but might afterwards. So take that also for a small consideration for your answer.

Please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084506/how-to-store-articles-or-other-large-texts-in-a-database

Comment: But the answer in that question is very mysql centric, so I thought of asking it again..mentioning the database I am looking to use i.e basically nosql. And the question is 4 years or more old, so hoping technologies have changed and so the answer might be different or atleast more helpful in recent times.

Comment: well, according to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/ogRVTfhrflo, mongo-db would not be your best option. I don't know much about couch though. and regarding new technologies, well... if you're not going for in-memory analytical databases, then you're out of luck. that's where most of the research of the last couple of years went into. [source: university life]

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin in-memory analytical databases? which are some of the best databases in that categories?

Comment: HANA. you should know though, that this is a quite expensive, yet powerful business database and I doubt you can afford it. I don't think there is anything in terms of free in memory dbms yet. The one that comes closest would by Hyrise, but it's far from finished. If I were you, I'd just go with either a flat-file dbms, or just use mysql which is imo, the most versatile of the free dbms. good luck!

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Do you still think storing the whole text as xml directly in database is the best option? Since the server side is mostly going to serve as api for the front-end, I was wishing to work it JSON and using xml would complicate it.

Comment: BBCode, JSON, XML, it's really all the same. They will behave similarily in terms of performance and which one you use is entirely up to you.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin Can you please remove the duplicate thing, so that I can I can get some better answers? It would be helpful

Comment: I know that, but having both at the same time is complicated. So I was hoping to find some better solution.

Comment: what I would advise you is just trying out multiple ways. then you will see what works and what not.

Comment: Thats a nice way to go about it. But I am running under a time constraint so wanted help people who have had some experience with it.

Comment: Questions asking for the StackOverflow community to pick your technology aren't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

Honestly MongoDB has been the best database for our NodeJS projects.  Before it had a 4MB maximum BSON document size, however it was increased to 8 MB and now to 16 MB with the latest versions.  This is actually a fair amount of text.  According to my calculation you should be able to store 2097152 characters in a 16MB object (though that includes the overhead)

Be aware that you are able to split up text into separate BSON documents very easily using [GridFS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/gridfs/).

I saw you were entertaining the idea of using flat files.  While this may be easy and fast, you will have a hard time indexing the text for later use.  MongoDB has the ability to index all your text and implementing search will be a fairly easy feature to add.

MongoDB is pretty fast and I have no doubt it will be the fastest database solution for you.  Development in NodeJS + MongoDB has taken months off projects for my firm compared to SQL based databases.  Also I have seen some pretty impressive [performance reviews](http://blog.softlayer.com/2012/mongodb-performance-analysis-bare-metal-v-virtual/) for it.  Keep in mind as well that those performance reviews were last year and I have seen even more impressive reviews but that was what I could find easily today.

Comment: But how would I differentiate between which text are of which size or font or colour if I just store them as text in mongo-db?

Comment: just store it as html in the database

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra we have a mini text editor implemented on our page and it just adds the proper html and css tags while editing.  we store the html and the css in the database and then render it again when it is displayed.

Comment: thanks. Will storing it in html still support text-search?

Comment: yes it will.  you just store the html as a string and make the string indexed.  please feel free to throw some karma my way by upvoting and marking correct :)  good luck