# How does Cassandra store variable data types like text

Tags: cassandra, bigdata

assumption is, Cassandra will store fixed length data in column family. like a column family: id(bigint), age(int), description(text), picture(blob). Now description and picture have no limit. How does it store that? Does Cassandra externalize through an ID -> location way?
For example, looks like, in relational databases, a pointer is used to point to the actual location of large texts. See [how it is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084506/how-to-store-articles-or-other-large-texts-in-a-database)
Also, looks like, in mysql, it is recommended to use char instead of varchar for better performance. I guess simply because, there is no need for an "id lookup". See: [mysql char vs varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526176/mysql-varchar-or-char-for-fixed-length-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cassandra stores individual cells (column values) in its on-disk files ("sstables") as a 32-bit length followed by the data bytes. So string values do **not** need to have a fixed size, nor are stored as pointers to other locations - the complete string appears as-is inside the data file.

The 32-bit length limit means that each "text" or "blob" value is limited to 2GB in length, but in practice, you shouldn't use anything even close to that - with Cassandra documentation [suggesting](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/refLimits.html) you shouldn't use more than 1MB. There are several problems with having very large values:

1. Because values are **not** stored as pointers to some other storage, but rather stored inline in the sttable files, these large strings get copied around every time sstable files get rewritten, namely during compaction. It would be more efficient to keep the huge string on disk in a separate files and just copy around pointers to it - but Cassandra doesn't do this.
2. The Cassandra query language (CQL) does not have any mechanism for store or retrieving a *partial* cell. So if you have a 2GB string, you have to retrieve it entirely - there is no way to "page" through it, nor a way to write it incrementally.
3. In Scylla, large cells will result in large latency spikes because Scylla will handle the very large cell atomically and not context-switch to do other work. In Cassandra this problem will be less pronounced but will still likely cause problems (the thread stuck on the large cell will monopolize the CPU until preempted by the operating system).

Comment: hmm right. in addition, if the text is updated to a larger field, then what? I guess, since data is always immutable, so it should be find, as, update results in new row with latest timestamp being added. eventually a compaction should take care of garbage rows.

Comment: Exactly. Cassandra on-disk files ("sstables") are indeed immutable - when new data comes in new sstable files are written with just the changes, and eventually two or more sstables are compacted together to create another up-to-date sstable.